# Autorizar cliente SPA usando client credential grant token y personal access token - Laravel Passport

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, oauth2, passport

Primero los pondré en contexto.

Estoy desarrollando una API Rest usando laravel y como metodo de autorizacion oauth2 usando como implementacion Laravel Passport.

Por otro lado estoy desarrollando un cliente Javascript (Single Page Application o SPA) que va a consumir la API Rest.

La situacion es la siguiente:

Algunos endpoints de la API Rest siempre deben ser accesibles por el cliente (**un cliente valido ya que la API no es publica**) y otros endpoints solo deben ser accesibles por el cliente cuando un usuario este logueado.

En un primer enfoque lo que se ha planteado es que cuando inicialmente se abra en el navegador la SPA, obtenga un token de tipo **Client Credential Grant Token** para que sea un cliente valido y pueda realizar peticiones a los endpoints "Basicos" de la API. Posteriormente cuando un usuario se loguee se generara un **Personal Access Token** el cual le permitira al cliente poder realizar peticiones a todos los endpoints de la API Rest.

Me encuentro un poco confundido en cuanto a cómo llevar esto a la practica.

Espero, por favor, puedan ayudarme.

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo la pregunta.
La forma en que yo lo haría es con password grant tokens.

La aplicación debería tener un client credentials grant token, que asegure que las peticiones solo se harán desde el cliente autorizado. Con cada petición debes enviar el token, que obtienes de [http://tu-aplicación.com/oauth/token](http://tu-aplicaci%C3%B3n.com/oauth/token).

Adicionalmente, habrá un endpoint que genere el token personal de tu usuario en la misma dirección, pasando estos parámetros:

```
'form_params' => [
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'client_id' => 'client-id',
        'client_secret' => 'el secret de tu cliente',
        'username' => 'taylor@laravel.com',
        'password' => 'la-contraseña',
        'scope' => '*',
    ],
```

que te retorna un token, el que deberás enviar tras cada petición del usuario logueado.

Comment: Hola amigo, bueno efectivamente como tu lo planteas es como en teoria yo quiero hacerlo pero tengo un par de dudas: La primera es si el token de tipo client credential que obtentra el cliente inicialmente debera ser remplazado por el token de tipo password grant que se genera cuando un usuario inicia sesion? y segundo, teniendo en cuenta que el cliente es una app en javascript entonces de que manera se pueden ocultar las credenciales de la aplicacion( es decir, el id y el secreto del cliente) de manera que nadie pueda verlo al inspeccionar el codido?

Comment: Hola, yo tengo el mismo problema, no se si ya pudiste resolverlo, me puedes decir como? 
Yo he leído sobre una forma de ocultar los datos del cliente y es creando un Api Proxy, la otra forma que he visto es restringiendo la IP donde se ejecuta el frontend.
Yo tambien quiero usar el Password Grant para el usuario y el client credential para la App, sobre todo para el registro y otras acciones.

Como lo solucionaste finalmente?